# Replace subString in string with Hibernate select query

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a table i would like to query with hibernate (java)
for exmaple this table has 2 column

```
full_name |  age
---------------------
Mr Dony   |   30
Mrs Clark |   32
Doc Who   |   43
```

i would like to replace each value of Doc  to Doctor show criteria result will look:

```
full_name |  age
---------------------
Mr Dony   |   30
Mrs Clark |   32
Doctor Who|   43
```

- I don't want to edit the acctual table data

  **i just want to use somthing like replace-subString how could i achieve it using hibernate?**

if that's matter my db's are PostgreSQL and vertica

Comment: This is a presentation-layer problem. It shouldn't be handled by Hibernate.

Comment: You want to manipulate the data received by a Hibernate query, not the actual table data, right? Are you trying to fetch data using JPQL or native SQL? 
Why you don't just manipulate the name after it has been fetched? 

Another possible solution would be to use REPLACE(fullName, "Doc", "Doctor"), but then you have to care about the right result mapping or at least about selecting all columns necessary for Hibernate to fetch automatically.

Comment: If you aren't allowed to use native SQL, then the DBMS you are using is irrelevant.

Comment: There is two ways: First - you could use native SQL and `Replace` function. Second - you could fetch all entities with HQL, replace strings with java and save entities back to database.

Comment: I don't need to update db, and native SQL its not why I need .

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate's Dialect is exactly for this job. What you can do is:

1. Implement a subclass of `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL81Dialect` or any of its descendants depending on actual PostgreSQL version.
2. Register a custom function (see PostgreSQL81Dialect's constructor) like below.
3. Declare your dialect with Hibernate
4. Then use it as you would with native query `update table_name set full_name = replace(full_name, 'Doc', 'Doctor')`. Note that this would replace all 'Doc' occurrences with 'Doctor'.

`public class PostgreSQL81DialectEx extends PostgreSQL81Dialect {
    public PostgreSQL81DialectEx() {
        registerFunction( "replace", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "replace(?1, ?2, ?3)") );
    }
}`